# Xcode: Button with background image and image over it and label

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

I would like to make a storyboard with the interface builder.
There are 12 buttons on the page, and all 12 buttons have the same background image (a button image). 
Over each button background I would like to (programmatically) show a distinct icon and a label.

I hope I could make my problem clear: 
I have static background images, but the icon on it should be resized to fit in the space.

On a click, the background image and the icon should become dark to visualize the click.

Is there a "best way" to do that? I feel I am a bit lost with the interface builder here.

Thank you very much.